# Smarty - How to hide questions under each section in a long form

Tags: css, forms, smarty

I'm very new to smarty and I'm trying to figure out a way to hide questions under each section title in a long form. I would need to add some id or class to the section name and some div to wrap to the questions under this specific section title so I can target them in css or js, but I'm breaking my head to find a way to do that with smarty.

Here is my code:

```
{if !empty($questionList)}
{foreach from=$questionList key='section' item='questions'}
{if !empty($section) }
    <tr class="ow_tr_first"><th colspan="3" class="section_label">{text key="base+questions_section_`$section`_label"}</th></tr>
{/if}
    {foreach from=$questions item='question' name='question'}
        <tr class="{cycle values='ow_alt1,ow_alt2'} {if $smarty.foreach.question.last}ow_tr_last{/if}">
            <td class="ow_label">
                {label name=$question.name}
            </td>
            <td class="ow_value">
                {input name=$question.name}
                <div style="height:1px;"></div>
                {error name=$question.name}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
    <tr class="ow_tr_delimiter"><td></td></tr>
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the current iteration of the first foreach to create unique identifiers/classes:

i.e.

```
{foreach from=$questionList key='section' item='questions' name='loop'}
    {if !empty($section) }
        <tr class="ow_tr_first"><th colspan="3" class="section_label" id="question{$smarty.foreach.loop.iteration}">{text key="base+questions_section_`$section`_label"}</th></tr>
    {/if}
    <tr class="question{$smarty.foreach.loop.iteration}_child {cycle values='ow_alt1,ow_alt2'} {if $smarty.foreach.loop.last}ow_tr_last{/if}">
```

So you willl end up with something like this:

```
<tr><th class="section_label" id="question1"></th></tr>
<tr class="question1_child">....</tr>
<tr class="question1_child">....</tr>
<tr class="question1_child">....</tr>
<tr><th class="section_label" id="question2"></th></tr>
<tr class="question2_child">....</tr>
<tr class="question2_child">....</tr>
<tr class="question2_child">....</tr>
```

and so on. That would be quite easy to target with css or javascript, i.e. hiding all .question1_child or showing all #id_name+'_child' when a certain .section_label is pressed

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). It is working half way, I don't get numbers with the id, it gives me something like that: `<tr class="ow_tr_first"> <th id="question" class="section_label" colspan="3">Astro</th> </tr> <tr class="question_child ow_alt1 "> <tr class="question_child ow_alt2 "> <tr class="question_child ow_alt1 ">`
Any idea why the iteration doesn't work?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was thinking in Smarty 3 and forgot to name the foreach. I edited the answer accordingly (notice name='loop' in the foreach tag and $smarty.foreach.loop.iteration instead of $smarty.foreach.questions.iteration)